# What does a "X" on the left side mean for an Ireland baptism record?

Tags: baptism-records, ireland, translation

What does a cross (X) on the left side mean for a Sologhead, Ireland baptism record? 
A number of rows have this.

Direct link (day 25):
https://registers.nli.ie/registers/vtls000632758#page/24/mode/1up

It doesn't seem to be a cancellation. As I can't see another baptism near the date (the child didn't die).
It wouldn't be a person making (signature), as that doesn't make sense for this document.

I'm wondering if it is something to do with costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the answer, basically just use the next number. The number must have been "23" with the cross next to it. In [Ancestry's](https://search.ancestry.co.uk/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=1&dbid=61039&h=4892267&ssrc=pt&tid=120872934&pid=201001930340&usePUB=true) database, they have used the next number which is "24" for the baptism date.